# Error Handling within a Loop for PivotTable object sorting

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I've been trying to sort PivotTable objects in VBA using a function I've attempted:

```
Public Function PTSort(PTName As String, PTFieldName as String, SortArray As Variant)

Dim m as Integer: m = 1 'Row counter
Dim i as Long 'Dummy Variable for cycling

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PTName).PivotFields(PTFieldName)
    .Parent.ManualUpdate = True
    For i = LBound(SortArray) To UBound(SortArray)
        With .PivotItems(SortArray(m - 1)) 'For in-code array
            .Position = m
        End With
    m = m + 1
    Next i
    .Parent.ManualUpdate = False
End With

End Function
```

Whilst this works well with a known set of elements within *SortArray*, I have a master list to follow whilst sorting (so as to standardise a few orders accross several PivotTables), in which the PivotTable need not necessarily contain all said PivotItems. I have hence improved it to the following:

```
Sub PTSort(PTName As String, PTFieldName as String, SortArray As Variant)

Dim m as Integer: m = 1
Dim i as Long
Dim k As Integer: k = 1 'To cycle the position independently from the array in the event of disjoint.

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PTName).PivotFields(PTFieldName)
    .Parent.ManualUpdate = True
    For i = LBound(SortArray) To UBound(SortArray)
        On Error GoTo ERRHANDLER:
        With .PivotItems(SortArray(k)) 'After parsing from range of cells into VariantArray, then does one not require the "-1"
            .Position = m
        End With
    m = m + 1
ExitHandler:
    k = k + 1
    Next i
    .Parent.ManualUpdate = False
End With
GoTo ENDEND:

ERRHANDLER:
GoTo EXITHANDLER:

ENDEND:
End Sub
```

The *OnError GoTo* seems to only work once though, irregardless of how high up placed it?

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as.aspx) on Visual Studio but I think it applies to VBA in the same way.

> An "enabled" error handler is one that is turned on by an On Error statement. An "active" error handler is an enabled handler that is in the process of handling an error.
>
> If an error occurs while an error handler is active (between the occurrence of the error and a Resume, Exit Sub, Exit Function, or Exit Property statement), the current procedure's error handler cannot handle the error. Control returns to the calling procedure

So after your code first gets to `On Error GoTo ERRHANDLER`, `ERRHANDLER` is *enabled*. Then when an error occurs `ERRHANDLER` is *activated* and handles the error. When you `GoTo EXITHANDLER` it stays active and still handles the error. The `On Error GoTo ERRHANDLER` has no effect at this point.

To re-enable the `ERRHANDLER` you need to use `Resume EXITHANDLER` instead of `GoTo EXITHANDLER`.

---

**Edit** on the `Resume` statement. There are three ways to use `Resume`: `Resume`, `Resume Next` and `Resume label`

`Resume` without an argument causes the code to resume at the line that caused the error. This obviously has to be used very careful as you must be absolutely certain that you fixed the problem or you'll end up in an infinite loop.

`Resume Next` causes the code to resume at the line after the line that caused the error.

`Resume Label` is almost the same as `GoTo Label` but with this you exit the error handler and resume normal code execution. The error handler is re-enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the information!
However I do not know how to use Resume with markers, for the prompt is consistently "Next" expected (i.e.: in On Error Resume Next)...

Comment: Just use the line `Resume EXITHANDLER` instead of the line `GoTo EXITHANDLER`. I'll edit in some more information.

Comment: IT WORKS. THANK YOU SO MUCH. :D